# Using external nodejs modules in Node-Webkit

Tags: node.js, module, node-webkit

I'm trying to use the nodejs 'edge' module from within my node-webkit application. e.g.

```
var edge = require('../node_modules/edge')
   var helloWorld = edge.func('async (input) => { return ".NET Welcomes " + input.ToString(); }');
      helloWorld('JavaScript', function (error, result) {
         if (error) throw error;
         console.log(result);
});
```

However, whenever I call it I get the following error:-

```
Uncaught Error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
C:\data\node_modules\edge\lib\native\win32\ia32\0.10.0\edge.node
```

If I run the same code outside of node-webkit using nodejs it works OK -

This also works OK from within NW:

```
 var dns = require('../node_modules/native-dns')
    var question = dns.Question({
        name: 'www.google.com',
        type: 'A'
    });

    var req = dns.Request({
        question: question,
        server: { address: '8.8.8.8', port: 53, type: 'udp' },
        timeout: 1000
    });

    req.on('timeout', function () {
        console.log('Timeout in making request');
    });

    req.on('message', function (err, answer) {
        answer.answer.forEach(function (a) {
            console.log(a.address);
        });
    });

    req.on('end', function () {
        console.log('Finished processing request');
    });

    req.send();
```

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you rebuild the modules with nw-gyp?

Comment: Yes-I did try this but still seeing the same problem

Comment: I've had similar trouble with native add-ons and decided to drop them entirely for now. Here's an issue I opened a bit ago: https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/issues/803

Comment: I'm also seeing the same exact error and I'm currently Googling, if I find anything I'll link it here.

Comment: Yeah, I've pretty much given up on node-WebKit now - can't recompile every time I want to use a library that uses native code. Adobe Brackets-shell looks very promising.